# Error in tensorflow "ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`. "

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I get this error sometimes but sometimes my model trains perfectly. Can anyone plz explain what is happeneing?
I am training a sequence to sequence model with attention mechanism for correcting grammer mistakes in a sentence.

**Code--**
**Encoder**

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length, enc_units):
    super().__init__()
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size
    self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
    self.input_length = input_length
    self.enc_units= enc_units
    self.lstm_output = 0
    self.lstm_state_h=0
    self.lstm_state_c=0
    
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.embedding = Embedding(input_dim=self.vocab_size, output_dim=self.embedding_dim, input_length=self.input_length,
                       mask_zero=True, name="embedding_layer_encoder")
    self.lstm = LSTM(self.enc_units, return_state=True, return_sequences=True, name="Encoder_LSTM")
    
def call(self, input_sentances, training=True):
    input_embedd                        = self.embedding(input_sentances)
    self.lstm_output, self.lstm_state_h,self.lstm_state_c = self.lstm(input_embedd)
    return self.lstm_output, self.lstm_state_h,self.lstm_state_c
def get_states(self):
    return self.lstm_state_h,self.lstm_state_c
```

**Decoder**

```
class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length, dec_units):
        super().__init__()
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
        self.dec_units = dec_units
        self.input_length = input_length

        # we are using embedding_matrix weights and not training the embedding layer  
        self.embedding = Embedding(input_dim=self.vocab_size, output_dim=self.embedding_dim, input_length=self.input_length,
                       mask_zero=True, name="embedding_layer_decoder", weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)  

        self.lstm = LSTM(self.dec_units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name="Encoder_LSTM")
    
    def call(self, target_sentances, state_h, state_c):
        target_embedd           = self.embedding(target_sentances)
        lstm_output, _,_        = self.lstm(target_embedd, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])  

        return lstm_output
```

**Model**

```
class vanilla_model(Model):
def __init__(self, encoder_inputs_length,decoder_inputs_length, output_vocab_size):
    super().__init__() 
    self.encoder = Encoder(vocab_size=v_perturbation, embedding_dim=300, input_length=encoder_inputs_length, enc_units=256)
    self.decoder = Decoder(vocab_size=v_correct, embedding_dim=300, input_length=decoder_inputs_length, dec_units=256)
    self.dense   = Dense(output_vocab_size, activation='softmax')
    
    
def call(self, data):
    input,output = data[0], data[1]
    encoder_output, encoder_h, encoder_c = self.encoder(input)
    decoder_output                       = self.decoder(output, encoder_h, encoder_c)
    output                               = self.dense(decoder_output)
    return output
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Have you defined the input_shape to the model? If not the model sets the input_shape to the shape of the first input it gets. So try adding something like this `inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))` and replace the (3,) to your desired shape.

Comment: My first layer in the encoder is an embedding layer. So, yes I have provided the input shape

Comment: @M.Innat I have updated the code